# Meaning of "active shooter" in news stories

Tags: meaning

I don't understand the way "active shooter" is being used in news stories relating to people being shot at an Arkansas night club.

[The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2017/jul/01/little-rock-nightclub-shooting-police):

> Police said the shooting at Power Ultra Lounge was the result of a dispute among club-goers and not an active shooter or terror-related incident.

Apparently the [actual police statement](http://www.cnn.com/2017/07/01/us/arkansas-club-shooting/) was:

> We do NOT believe this incident was an active shooter or terror related incident. It appears to have been a dispute at a concert

What is the distinction between an "active shooter" and other shooters who are intentionally shooting people?

Comment: The shooter was definitely active at the time of the shooting but now he's not.  I agree that it is strange that the police would indicate that it never was an active shooter incident.

Comment: @thomj1332 'Active shooter' means that they went into the club with the sole purpose of killing people.  According to the police report, this was not the case, it was instead an escalation between club goers.  'Active shooter' does not mean that they were 'actively shooting people' in this sense.

Comment: @macellothearcance, not according to the definition given by Homeland security...see answer below...An active shooter is "an individual actively engaged in killing..."

Comment: @marcellothearcane another definition is "An active shooter is considered to be a suspect or assailant whose activity is immediately causing serious injury or death and has not been contained" http://police.vt.edu/programs-training/emergency-training/active-shooter.html

Comment: @DavePhD exactly, so not a malicious intent initially is the point.

Comment: Well, that person sure did a lot of hurt for being an inactive shooter.

Comment: @marcellothearcane It seems malicious to me.  It wasn't an accidental shooting.

Comment: @DavePhD malicious *once there was the dispute*. The point is, it wasn't a club in which someone just came into and started shooting, they were already there, had an argument, and then pulled the gun. I think that's the distinction the police give.  EDIT: In the light of the latest answer, it looks like I'm wrong!

Comment: Euphemisms are often adopted to supplant a more appropriate term like "mass-homicidal wacko"

Answer (score 16):

The Little Rock police were not using the phrase correctly.  The Arkansas shooter was indeed active "in a confined and populated area" during the shooting therefore he was an active shooter (per USDHS definition given by other answerer).

The term is used so people (including first responders) can know whether the shooter is still active and dangerous or the threat is neutralized (for whatever reason).

See image below for an example of the correct usage:

[image]

Answer (score 10):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_shooter) says that "active shooter names the perpetrator of a type of mass murder marked by rapidity, scale, randomness and suicide".

And the [United States Department of Homeland Security](https://www.dhs.gov/xlibrary/assets/active_shooter_booklet.pdf) (pdf) defines an active shooter as "an individual actively engaged in killing or attempting to kill people in a conﬁned and populated area; in most cases, active shooters use firearms(s) [sic] and there is no pattern or method to their selection of victims".

Comment: OK, so in Arkansas the shooter(s) were attempting to kill people in a confined and populated area, using firearms, but maybe it wasn't random.

Comment: This book makes it sound like only attempting to kill in a confined or populated space is required, not random selection of victims.  https://books.google.com/books?id=oeX3CAAAQBAJ&pg=PA7&dq=%22active+shooter%22+definition&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjtq6_eu-3UAhVDOj4KHeZnD8gQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%22active%20shooter%22%20definition&f=false Says it is mostly shooters in commercial buildings, like workplace shootings.

Comment: Good find. Sometimes you need a basic but imperfect jargon to quickly group things. Of course a philosophical discussion would blur the margins but that isn't the point.

Comment: Yes, it seems like there are many definitions, but I think the best source is directly from USDHS themselves.

Comment: Gotta admit that I was pretty surprised the first time that I heard the expression used when there was NOT a firearm involved